# Android PIE SecurityException

Tags: android, android-service, android-permissions, securityexception

When i changed target version to 28 i started to get `SecurityException` crashes when i'm trying to display notification by `NotificationManager.notify()` from `FirebaseService`.
I read behavior changes for Android 9, but adding of `FOREGROUND_SERVICE` permission doesn't help me. The problem occurs on devices with Android 9 only, but i can't reproduce it on Samsung S10.

here is logs:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: 
  at android.os.Parcel.createException (Parcel.java:1966)
  at android.os.Parcel.readException (Parcel.java:1934)
  at android.os.Parcel.readException (Parcel.java:1884)
  at android.app.INotificationManager$Stub$Proxy.enqueueNotificationWithTag (INotificationManager.java:1653)
  at android.app.NotificationManager.notifyAsUser (NotificationManager.java:429)
  at android.app.NotificationManager.notify (NotificationManager.java:379)
  at android.app.NotificationManager.notify (NotificationManager.java:355)
  at com.example.Utils.onNotificationReceived (Utils.java:201)
  at com.example.FirebaseService.onMessageReceived (FirebaseService.java:51)
  at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService.zzd (FirebaseMessagingService.java:60)
  at com.google.firebase.iid.zzg.run (zzg.java:4)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
  at com.google.android.gms.common.util.concurrent.zza.run (zza.java:6)
  at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:764)
Caused by: android.os.RemoteException: 
  at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.checkGrantUriPermissionLocked (ActivityManagerService.java:12755)
  at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.checkGrantUriPermission (ActivityManagerService.java:12772)
  at com.android.server.notification.NotificationRecord.visitGrantableUri (NotificationRecord.java:1147)
  at com.android.server.notification.NotificationRecord.calculateGrantableUris (NotificationRecord.java:1123)
  at com.android.server.notification.NotificationRecord.<init> (NotificationRecord.java:208)
```

Manifest permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
```

Could there be an issue in setting sound for channel from `raw` directory?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54120745/android-9-0-notificationmanager-notify-throwing-java-lang-securityexception